# MASK csv columns using python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mask

I have below requirement to MASK 3 columns (MAILID,SSN,CCNO) with X (each char with X) using python3, I am trying with lambda function, but not getting exact output. any help on this?

```
ID  NAME     MAILID          SSN     CCNO SEX
 1   ABC  abc@gmail.com  123-456-789  123456789012  M
 2   PQR  prq@yahoo.com  765-123-789  456789123456  F
 3   XYX  xyz@redif.com  123-365-789  987612347799  M
```

Desired output:

```
 ID  NAME     MAILID          SSN     CCNO SEX
 1   ABC  XXX@XXXXX.XXX  XXX-XXX-XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXX  M
 2   PQR  XXX@XXXXX.XXX  XXX-XXX-XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXX  F
 3   XYX  XXX@XXXXX.XXX  XXX-XXX-XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXX  M
```

I'm using below code for SSN, its coming as expected. But for the remaining MAILID and CCNO, its not coming.

```
df = pd.read_csv("input-csv.csv")
df.SSN = df.SSN.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\d', 'X', x, count=9))
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

works as desired. Btw. pandas has a *replace* functionality for strings. Using

```
for col in ['MAILID','SSN','CCNO']:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace('[a-zA-Z0-9]','X')
```

saves you the apply and importing of re

Comment: I am confused, if the dtype is integer like you cannot put characters in. You would need to first convert the int's to strings using 'df[col].astype(str)'

Comment: My doubt is, in case of CCNO, validation failing because it has only numbers? how to handle the case for CCNO column??

Comment: for col in ['CCNO']:
    df[col] = df[col].int.replace('[0-9]','X')
I mean in case of int columns, it is failing. Any alternate solution or any change here ?